# How do I remove duplicate property entity effectively

Tags: java

There is a `List<Entity> dataList`, some multiple properties need to be unique, so we wanna remove the duplication. For example, below is my entity:

```
public class Entity {

  String A;

  String B;

  String C;
}
```

we wanna get a entity list with distinct(A, B, C), means there is no 2 entities with same (A and B and C), but separately A or B or C can be same. The method is `dataList = removeDuplication(dataList).`

How should I write logic has high performance?

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us your solution

Comment: The simplest way would be to implement `equals` in that class and use a `Set` to do that for you.

Comment: You could use `Stream` as well, it isn't that hard to find solutions to that problem in Google.

Comment: yep, will use set and overwrite the equals

Comment: Overwrite equals and hashcode methods:                      dataList.stream.collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work. anyone can help to check it? below is my codes:

Comment: Share source code

Comment: post code details to below answer block cause comment length limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added equals and hashcode like below:

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Entity that = (Entity) o;
    return Objects.equals(getA(), that.getA())
        && Objects.equals(getB(), that.getB())
        && Objects.equals(getC(), that.getC()));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getA(), getB(), getC());
  }
```

in method, I use this:

```
entityList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

have no idea why it doesn't work, anybody knows that?